# Visual Studio Database Deployment - Script not running in SQLCMD mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd, database-project, database-deployment

I have a SQL Server 2008 Database Project that I'm attempting to deploy using Visual Studio 2010. When I click deploy, the build works fine, but after it creates the deployment script and begins to execute it, I get the following errors:

> Error 8   SQL80001: 'DatabaseName' is not a recognized option.
>
> Error 7   SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Looking at the deployment script, it has the following lines:

> :setvar DatabaseName "DEV_DB"

...

> GO
>
> :on error exit

So it looks like SQL Server is not running the deployment script in SQLCMD mode to understand that syntax. If I'm copying and pasting into SSMS, I can set that option, but I want to deploy straight from Visual Studio. Where is the setting to have VS run this script in SQLCMD mode **OR** How can I set the script to not generate using SQLCMD syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running the generated SQLCMD script interactively (i.e. through the VS query window) or is the Deploy step doing this for you?

Comment: It's running as part of the deployment. When I click Deploy, I believe it's generating the SQL script and deploying it in the same step.

Comment: That's odd. If you create a new db project from scratch, do you get the same error or does it only happen with this particular project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make SQLCMD Mode 'Sticky' in Database Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057776/is-it-possible-to-make-sqlcmd-mode-sticky-in-database-projects)