# Can I use SQLCMD Commands in Visual Studio Database Project Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sqlcmd, database-project

I have a lot of SQL that is the same over multiple stored procedures.

For example most procedures have the same variables declared, and is in the same try catch block to handle errors.

I'd like to use the `:r` command so that I can write this code in one file and just import it into each sp. I can use that command in the pre and post build scripts but I can't get it working within a normal 'Build' type database object.

Example:

[image]

SQL within `\Shared\CommonVariables`:

[image]

Within `[p_An_Example]`:

[image]

The error just says "SQL46010: Incorrect Syntax near \."

-

If I wrap the path in quotes that error is replaced by one on 'BEGIN':

[image]

"SQL46010: Incorrect Syntax near BEGIN."

-

Is there anything I can do to get this working? At the moment `[p_An_Example]` has the `Build` Build Action property, and `\Shared\CommonVariables` is set to `None`.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2017, the database project is pointing to a 2008 database, SQLCMD is installed etc)

**Edit: Not a duplication because I do have SQLCMD mode on... but it turns out SQLCMD commands are not available within stored procedure statements**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make SQLCMD Mode 'Sticky' in Database Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057776/is-it-possible-to-make-sqlcmd-mode-sticky-in-database-projects)

Comment: The T-SQL source code used to build the model may contain SQLCMD variables but not SQLCMD commands, like `:r`.`.  I'm not aware of a way to include files during the build process that become part of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes I've checked and I do have SQLCMD mode on, so this must be the issue... its just not possible within SPs. Thank you for the confirmation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the option is in SQL -> Execution Settings -> SQLCMD Mode:

[image]

Note, however, that you can't include sqlcmd code within an SP, as the DBMS can't interpret the code, it's purely for using in a coding environment; such as within SSMS/VS.

Comment: Turns out I do have this option enabled, but as DanGuzman said in the comments it turns out SQLCMD commands aren't available within CREATE PROC statements

Comment: @SamuelO'Connor Yes, that's correct. They can't be within the definition of an object (as I mention in the answer), as the DBMS itself doesn't have SQLCMD mode. When using SQLCMD statements it's the application (VS/SSMS) that interprets and deals with them, not the DBMS.

Answer (score 9):

In `Visual Studio 2019`, you can do the same by opening the file with the `SQLCMD` statements, then click the last icon in the new view to make the errors go away:

[image]