# Silent error SQL80001 in Visual Studio (SQL Server tools)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

I need some help to disable error in Visual Studio

- I created a project with a `.sql` file inside with Postgres syntax
- I excluded the file from any build action
- But this results in an entry in the error list : [ErrorList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anoEG.png)

I tried to exclude the error with a `editorconfig` file like this...

```
[*.sql]
disable_formatter = false
dotnet_naming_rule.SQL80001 = false
dotnet_diagnostic.SQL80001.severity = none
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

But that doesn't work - I could also not find the analyzer name.

The only possibility that I found it's disable intellisense option but it's not acceptable cause the setting impact the global configuration and I have others project sql

[IntellisenseError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzGlt.png)

Can someone help me?

Comment: For me, this post solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839951/can-i-use-sqlcmd-commands-in-visual-studio-database-project-stored-procedure/51840096

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an option in your case, but you can suppress SQL warnings by entering the warning numbers in the project properties page.

Remove 'SQL', keep only the number. In your case, you would have 80001.

[image]