# Is it possible to use a SQLCMD variable in a Visual Studio Database (SSDT) Project without enclosing it in square brackets or single quotes?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd

I know I can use a SQLCMD variable in a Visual Studio database (SQL Server Data Tools) project if I enclose it within square brackets or single quotes.

For example, something like

```
:setvar StringFilter "One"
    
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    StrValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, StrValue)
VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');

SELECT ID, 
    StrValue
FROM @tbl
WHERE StrValue = '$(StringFilter)';
```

However, is it possible to use a SQLCMD variable without enclosing it within square brackets or single quotes?

For example, something like

```
:setvar Collation "Latin1_General_CI_AS"
    
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    StrValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, StrValue)
VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');

SELECT ID, 
    StrValue COLLATE $(Collation)
FROM @tbl;
```

Using a SQLCMD variable like this to set the collation would work in SQL Server Management Studio.  However, I haven't been able to get it to work in a Visual Studio database project because it throws a syntax error when the project builds.  Is there any setting or any way to allow SQLCMD variables to work in Visual Studio without enclosing them in square brackets or single quotes?

**EDIT:** Here are the syntax error Visual Studio is displaying:

[image: Visual Studio syntax errors]

**EDIT 2:** As Deirdre O'Keary mentions in her answer, it works in a post-deployment script.  I should have been more specific: I'm wanting to use a SQLCMD variable to set the collation in a stored procedure which will be built as part of the database project.  The syntax errors above occur when the project builds.  By default post-deployment scripts aren't built as part of the project which is how SQLCMD variables in those scripts don't generate an error.  However, stored procedures are part of the build which is why I see the error.  Is there any setting that would allow a stored procedure/trigger/function/etc to build successfully with a SQLCMD variable not enclosed in quotes or square brackets?

Comment: I suspect you want `COLLATE [$(Collation)]`. Not in a position to test, hence a comment.

Comment: @ThomA: Thanks.  I tried it but I still get a syntax error.

Comment: What's the syntax error you're receiving?

Comment: @DeirdreO'Leary: I've edited the question to include a screenshot of the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave, without the braces around `$(Collation)` works as I expect it to in Visual Studio 2022 when I tested it as a post-deployment script. I tried both publishing directly to a target database & generating a script.

I wonder if this is a case of your expectations differing from how Visual Studio treats SQLCMD variables. Generating the script as part of the Publish step will show you that substitution does not happen at that stage. Instead, substitution happens when the script is executed against the database with SQLCMD mode enabled.

I.e. the script generated by Visual Studio on publish is:

```
:setvar Collation "Latin1_General_CI_AS"

DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    StrValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, StrValue)
VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');

SELECT ID, 
    StrValue COLLATE $(Collation)
FROM @tbl;
```

Whereas what is executed on the database when that script is run with SQLCMD mode triggering the substitution is the following. But you don't "see" the substitution happening.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    StrValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, StrValue)
VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');

SELECT ID, 
    StrValue COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM @tbl;
```

By the way, your example also works fine without the quote marks around the collation setting so you can just use `:setvar Collation Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Comment: Thanks Deirdre.  I realise from your answer that my question wasn't clear: I'm looking to add a SQLCMD variable to a file that is built with the project, like a stored procedure.  Post-deployment scripts are not part of the build by default so don't throw the syntax error when the project builds.  However, adding a SQLCMD variable to a stored proc (which has Build Action = Build) results in a syntax error on build.  I'm hoping there is a setting that allows Visual Studio to not throw an error if an unenclosed SQLCMD variable is included in the build.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I've never tried to use SQLCMD in a built object before & unfortunately I'm not in a position to test it at the moment. But from someone else asking the same question, it seems like it's not possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839951/can-i-use-sqlcmd-commands-in-visual-studio-database-project-stored-procedure